# How to make sticky DIY electrode pads (for muscle stimulation)? (Can I ask?)

Tags: support

Information about this essential thing is hard to find. It should be on the stack exchange. But where?
Can I post it here? If not Any idea where?

Comment: You already asked this on medical science. See my response there.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not about exercise, it doesn't really fit our site.

But there is the [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) site, as well as [LifeHacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) that might be a better fit.

Make sure to read their respective Help Centers to assess what's on and off topic though.

Comment: `Since it's not about exercise, it doesn't really fit our site`. I'm not sure to understand: EMS is just another way to exercise the muscles (the device is made for that). There is not just one way to train muscles. And by the way it also helps the muscle to recover after classical fitness exercices.

Comment: @JinSnow - If the question was about how and where to apply the electrodes, I might be more inclined to see it as a fit. But since your question is about how to *make* electrode pads, it becomes more of a tech support question, and the exercise part is only indirectly related.

Comment: this argument is valid (but reasoning looks like a rationalisation: what comes first isn't the argument, but the conclusion ; -) )

Comment: Well, yeah. I told you the conclusion first, and then you said you were confused, so I elaborated on the rationalisation.